# Referenced name for my WCF service - Customers.svc or CustomersWcfDS.svc?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, wcf

I have the following Visual Studio Web application structure:

```
CustomerManagement\
  - Services
    - Customers.aspx
      - Customers.aspx.cs
    - CustomersWcfDS.svc
  - Default.aspx
  - web.config
```

The following code is inside the `<configuration>` in the web.config file:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ICustomers" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://localhost:1112/Services/Customers.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ICustomers" contract="CustomersService.ICustomers" name="BasicHttpBinding_ICustomers" />
</client>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
```

I build the project and enter the following URL but there is no reactions.

```
http://localhost:1112/Services/Customers.svc
```

I also tried the following:

```
http://localhost:1112/Services/CustomersWcfDS.svc
```

and also

```
http://localhost:1110/Services/Customers.svc
```

and

```
http://localhost:1110/Services/CustomersWcfDS.svc
```

(The port 1110 was tested because of the Project Properties `Port number` was set to `1110`.)

but it still fail to display something similar like the following illustration

[image]

So, is there any expert that can advise me where have my WCF service URL gone to?

Answer (score 0):

Hi based on your image,

I think you have renamed the service name as Customers.svc . But still it refering to the previous one. What you can do is try to find the "SimpleService.svc" in your entire solution
and rename it as Customers.svc. If you have any problem put it as a comment.

Comment: Strange, I find that the correct URL is http://localhost:1110/CustomerManagement/Services/CustomersWcfDS.svc. May I know why it is there and should I can the `<endpoint address=...>` to this URL?

Comment: As i already told you have tried to rename some interface/class thats why it is there. Try renaming it, otherwise share the project will try to help you.

Comment: It does not seem to work, I have raise a new question here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14314556/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-app-web-1btizmpz

Comment: why dont you share your code..its hard to identify the error !