# Could not load file or assembly 'App_Web_1btizmpz,

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, wcf

I encounter the following error:

`Could not load file or assembly 'App_Web_1btizmpz, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.`

Please advise.

The error appear when the following URL is enter:

(I have restarted the IIS server but the error still appear)

```
http://localhost:1110/CustomerManagement/Services/CustomersWcfDS.svc
```

Details of the settings is shown here - [The remote server returned an unexpected response: (405) Method Not Allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14313685/the-remote-server-returned-an-unexpected-response-405-method-not-allowed)

Comment: at first, try to build all

Comment: Perhaps your IIS-Worker-Pool-Account has no access to temporary ASP.NET files?